# Opencart module controller index function data source

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, opencart

Some module controllers on a website I work with have data passed to their index function. How is it done? I can't find the source file that sends data to controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$this->config->get` object is set initially from `index.php` file as a current setting and not as a module tracking. The $setting array passed into the index method is the one initialized whenever the current module is loaded at that point in the loop. The $setting object should be initialized automatically by ensuring that the same basic key names are being added from the admin modules before loading the array on the store-front end. Additional key names can be added along with the basic key names as there should be no problem to re-catch those additional keys by using the $setting array either. This methodology should not interfere with other modules nor with other basic key names since each $setting array are being fetched accordingly from the database.

> You can also check `module table` in your opencart database to understand it more clearly.

**Source** [Link](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=92945)